# How to use like query on a string having whitespace character in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Function should work if parameter contains space. For example: "foo bar". But not working.

```
function cat_find($title = '')
{
  $field = 'category_caption';
  $this->db->select("id, category_caption");
  $this->db->like('LOWER('.$field.')', strtolower($title));
  $this->db->from("table");

  return $this->db->get('', 30)->result_array();
}
```

this function called from ajax method and use form input value.

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? do you get any errors?

Comment: no error but it is not return any record. i have records with space in the category caption column.

Comment: `echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();`

Comment: as @splash58 toldyou use `sessage_log('debug', 'QUERY: ' . $this->db->get_compiled_select())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLVED**. I should decode the value because it come from AJAX and if the string have space or any unicode character, it will be encoded.

"Foo%20Bar" not match with "Foo Bar".

simply before my query:

```
$title=urldecode($title);
```

Answer (score 0):

breaks a string into an array with  explode and then use in your query

```
function cat_find($title = NULL)
    {
      $field = 'category_caption';
      $this->db->select("id, category_caption");
      $title = explode(" ", $title);
      $this->db->like('LOWER('.$field.')',strtolower($title[0]));
      $this->db->or_like('LOWER('.$field.')', strtolower($title[1]));

      $this->db->from("table");

      return $this->db->get('', 30)->result_array();
    }
```